# How to solve error : [ERROR] Failed to load the component

Tags: magento2

console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/shipping" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/tax" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Weee/js/view/cart/totals/weee" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Vertex_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/tax-messages" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
2console-output-handler.js:34

```
   [2022-09-22 09:28:34] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component.
```

ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
shipping-invalidate-mixin.js:12

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vertexAddressValidationConfig')
at shipping-invalidate-mixin.js:12:40
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650:33)
at context.execCb (resolver.js:145:31)
at Module.check (require.js:866:51)
at Module.enable (require.js:1143:22)
at Module.init (require.js:774:26)
at callGetModule (require.js:1170:63)
at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1544:21)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1671:29)
```

agreements-assigner.js:12

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkoutAgreements')
at agreements-assigner.js:12:50
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650:33)
at context.execCb (resolver.js:145:31)
at Module.check (require.js:866:51)
at Module.enable (require.js:1143:22)
at Module.init (require.js:774:26)
at callGetModule (require.js:1170:63)
at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1544:21)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1671:29)
```

Comment: Did you found the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile 
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Yes, I already try this, but still not working.